# How can I list all files which are direct or independent dependencies of a make/cmake target?

Tags: makefile, cmake, dependencies

I use CMake to build my C++/Qt projects.

To build `MyProgram`:

```
cd build
cmake /path/to/src
make MyProgram
```

CMake generates various Makefiles and then builds `MyProgram`. All fine and normal.

If `/path/to/src/foo.bar` is a dependency of `MyProgram` then running `touch /path/to/src/foo.bar; make MyProgram` will cause some parts to recompile and relink.

As well as code sources, I'm also interested in *all* other dependencies, such as the various `CMakeLists.txt` files themselves, or other files which CMake uses to configure and generate other sources. Anything and everything that CMake considers to be a dependency; that is: all the things which CMake puts into the Makefiles as dependencies.

How do I get a list of all files which are a dependency of `MyProgram`?

Comment: `Anything and everything that CMake considers to be a dependency` - It is very unlikely that CMake gives you a **full list** of such things. However, there are many [target's properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets), which can tell you about specific classes of such dependencies. E.g. *SOURCES* property contains list of source files for executable/library, *LINK_LIBRARIES* contains list of libraries linked into the target, *SOURCE_DIR* refers to a directory, which `CMakeLists.txt` creates a target.

Comment: Is there a command-line dump for such things?

Comment: CMake doesn't provide such command-line tool. However, because CMake generates Makefiles, you may try Makefile-related tools.